# Django custom DATETIME_INPUT_FORMAT

Tags: django

I created a Django form to handle date inputs:

```
class WINDOW_START_Form(forms.Form):
  WINDOW_START = forms.DateTimeField(label="WINDOW_START")
```

The view that uses this looks like this:

```
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form_start    = WINDOW_START_Form(request.POST)

    if form_start.is_valid():
        WS = form_start.cleaned_data['WINDOW_START']
    else:
        logger.error("The start date format you entered is incorrect.")
```

I want the form to be able to accept the day-of-year format (eg: 2015/320 - where the second number is the day of the year) in addition to all of the default formats listed in Django's `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS`.

To do this I've added a line in the `settings.py` file like this:

```
from django.conf.global_settings import DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS += ('%Y/%z','%Y-%z', '%Y-%z %H:%M:%S','%Y-%z %H:%M:%S.%f',)
```

According to Django's documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date) `%z` is the format character for day of year so it should read in 2015/203 as a valid date, but when I enter that in the search field Django doesn't read it as valid and `.is_valid()` in my view comes up false.

Can anyone tell me if I'm missing something?

Comment: Check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files

Comment: @intelis do you know if this works with a list of formats I want to include? Like:
    
`DATETIME_FORMAT = ['format 1', 'format 2', 'format 3']`

Answer (score 1):

This post is old, but for future reference, you're using the incorrect identifier for DOY (Day of Year). It should be `%j` instead of `%z`, when used in this way.

I made the exact same mistake, and it took me forever to figure out what was wrong.

The Django template filter uses `z` instead of `j`, for Day of Year. So it is easy to get them confused.

This is working for me:

```
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS += (
                           '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', 
                           '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f', 
                           '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M', 
                           '%Y-%jT%H:%M:%S.%f', 
                           '%Y-%jT%H:%M:%S', 
                           '%Y-%jT%H:%M',
                           '%Y-%j_%H:%M:%S.%f', 
                           '%Y-%j_%H:%M:%S', 
                           '%Y-%j_%H:%M',
                           )
```